# unique values of each group

Tags: r, unique

I want to find the unique names of y for each x in the data frame df. For example

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1)
y <- c("alf", "be", "be", "cmg", "be", "cmg", "cmg")

df <- data.frame(x,y)
df
          x   y
       1  1 alf
       2  2  be
       3  3  be
       4  1 cmg
       5  2  be
       6  3 cmg
       7  1 cmg
```

What I want is, the unique values for each value of x

```
   x   y
   1 alf
     cmg

   2  be

   3  be
     cmg
```

what I have done is

```
un_values<- df %>% group_by(x) %>% summarize(un_values=unique(y))
```

but it gives only the unique y values without the x values.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

If  you want a data.frame as output, try:

```
> aggregate(y~x, data=df, unique)
  x y.1 y.2
1 1 alf cmg
2 2  be cmg
3 3  be cmg
```

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me

```
lapply(split(y, x), unique)
```

Answer (score 1):

And with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(x) %>% arrange(x) %>% distinct()
# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   x [3]
      x      y
  <dbl> <fctr>
1     1    alf
2     1    cmg
3     2     be
4     3     be
5     3    cmg
```

Note that since you have only one variable (y) besides your group variable (x), `dplyr::distinct(df)` should also work fine